# Why is Python giving me a Variable Scope Error even after declaring global variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, global-variables

I'm a Python beginner, and I'm trying to create a basic program where the user creates an account by entering a username, password and confirms the password. I've seen other questions and answers on this site, but none of them work for me. The following is my code (I am using Python 2.7):

```
global username, password, surePassword

def createAcc():
    print "Welcome! Create an account below: "
    username = raw_input("Select a username: ")
    password = raw_input("Select a password: ")
    surePassword = raw_input("Confirm your password: ")
    confirmPassword()

def confirmPassword():
    if surePassword == password:
        print "Account created successfully!"
    else:
        surePassword = raw_input("Error: Incorrect confirmation. Re-enter password: ")
        confirmPassword()

createAcc()
```

When I run this program, I am able to enter a username and password. However, once I confirm the password, it gives me the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 17, in <module>
    createAcc()
 line 8, in createAcc
    confirmPassword()
 line 11, in confirmPassword
    if surePassword == password:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'surePassword' referenced before assignment
```

The program was supposed to just tell me whether my confirmed password is correct, and if it isn't, then tell me to re-enter the password until it is correct. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `global` declarations go in the scope that needs to access the global variable, not in the global scope. (`global` at global scope really ought to be a SyntaxError.)

Comment: Note, there's no good reason to be using global variables here anyway.

Comment: @user2357112 I declared the variables to be global inside both the functions instead, and it worked! Thanks.